# Error in SSIS package when script component is trying to retrieve errorCode and errorColumn-[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: No object exists with the ID 0

Tags: error-handling, ssis, script-component

I have a SSIS package where I am using a script component in DFT to retrieve the error column and error description from an insert into a SQL table.

My code is below. However, after the DFT is done (it completes all its steps) the package cannot continue onto the next DFT task with error of

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: No object exists with the ID 0.

My code is below for the component

I have tried to delete the script component and re-create it but this did not work

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.ErrorDescription = this.ComponentMetaData.GetErrorDescription(Row.ErrorCode);
    IDTSComponentMetaData130 componentMetaData = this.ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
    Row.ErrorColumnName = componentMetaData.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn);
}
```

Error Description and Error Column get to error table but package does not continue.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a script component in DFT to retrieve the error column and error description from an insert into a SQL table.

If you are reading data from the Error output of OLE DB destination and you are using `Table or View - Fast Load` option as `Access Mode`, you are not able to retrieve the Column name since you are performing Bulk Insert operation.

If you need to get the Error Column name you cannot use `Fast Load` option, you need to perform Row-by row insert by selecting `Table or View` access mode which decrease the insert performance.

If you are not reading from OLE DB Destination error output, then refer to the following article for a step by step guide:

- [Retrieve the column causing an error in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4066/retrieve-the-column-causing-an-error-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: I am not using fast load option so I am not sure this is the issue

Comment: I don't think this is related to fast load option. Fast load prevent only redirecting the error row, it will redirect the whole batch